# How to make my layout look simillar in all Android devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know how can I achieve this using dimens file.

I have tried creating dimens file for different densities and smallest screen width but I don't know  how much size I should specify in each file.

For example in dimens.xml I have `<dimen name="title_margin">8dp</dimen>` then how much it should be in other dimens files?

Which one is correct for creating dimens file: either to go with Smallest Screen width or Density?

Comment: You can work on height and width ratio of the specific screen. i.e. dynamic width and height.

Comment: When posting here, please use the preview window before posting. Your XML code was not visible in this case, because the editor thought it was HTML. You need to use the formatting tools provided.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create your own dimensions, There's this cool library called **SDP - a scalable size unit** https://github.com/intuit/sdp

They have already mapped all dimensions for different densities.

They also have a library for text sizes too - **SSP - a scalable size unit for texts**
https://github.com/intuit/ssp